# Non blocking UDP receiver in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, sockets, user-interface, udp, simulink

I'm creating a MATLAB GUI using the app designer (very similar to, but better than, GUIDE) which I want to use to monitor the data output of my simulink model in **real time**.

In other words, I have a simulink model and a GUI, both running in the same MATLAB instance and I want to send packets over UDP from the simulink model and use that data in my GUI to update plots. However, I don't know how to read the data from the UDP packet without blocking.

Is there a way to bind a handler when a packet is received so that I can execute a function to update plots/fields?

Comment: If you're communicating over UDP, why not just run the GUI in a separate instance of MATLAB?

Comment: @Suever Because I need to be able to access my simulink model from the gui as well to write its model workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, beside `BytesAvailableFcn` matlab has the [datagramreceivedfcn](https://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/datagramreceivedfcn.html) to call your custom function on new dagatrams, which is nonblocking while fread/fscanf are blocking (temporarily). 
 
 Regarding callbacks in matlab read [events and cbs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/events-and-callbacks_f13-51459.html#f13-43866)

Compilable standalone could look like:

```
%% standalone main
%{
    see docs/*
%}

function exitcode = main(port, remotePort)

% sanitize input
if(~exist('port','var') || ~exist('remotePort','var'))
    disp(['args: port remotePort']);
    exit(1);
end

if ischar(port)
    port=str2num(port);
end
if ischar(remotePort)
    remotePort=str2num(remotePort);
end

% create udp object
u = udp('127.0.0.1',remotePort, 'LocalPort', port);

% connect the UDP object to the host
fopen(u);
exitcode = 0;

% since we poll, suppress warning
warning('off','instrument:fscanf:unsuccessfulRead');
warning VERBOSE

% specify callback on datagram
while true
    msgEnc= fscanf(u);
    % timed out without datagram
    if isempty(msgEnc)
        continue
    end
    % do sth with msgEnc (which is a readable string)
    fprintf(u, 'heard sth'); %answer
end
end
```

If you would like to use simulink block use [udpreceive](https://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udpreceive.html)
which has a non-blokcking capability

> A First In First Out (FIFO) buffer receives the data. At every time
>   step, the Data port outputs the requested values from the buffer. In a
>   nonblocking mode, the Status port indicates if the block has received
>   new data.